# How to take sql server database backup everyday 2 A.M automatically using sql query?

Tags: sql-server

I would like to take Database backup in sql server 2012 automatically. Everyday 2 A.M using sql query.

Comment: Why can you not use a SQL Agent Job?

Comment: Check my post - http://blog.devart.com/sql-server-typical-maintenance-plans-automated-database-backups.html

Comment: Ola is your friend. https://ola.hallengren.com/